# Tests are not able to interact with the elements after enabling the basic auth in the selenium grid

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Tests are not able to interact with the elements after enabling the basic auth in the grid. I have enabled the basic auth in the grid running on eks v0.20.1:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/selenium-grid-0.20.1/charts/selenium-grid/values.yaml#L13

```
Unable to parse: <html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
</body>
</html>
org.openqa.selenium.json.JsonException: Unable to determine type from: <. Last 1 characters read: <
Build info: version: '4.11.0', revision: '040bc5406b'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '13.5', java.version: '17.0.6'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

Session needs to be authenticated as well.

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/grid/configuration/toml_options/#basic-auth-enabled

Thank you @Diemol